# Can't install any RubyGems, invalid argument error when connecting to sources [gem 2.4.8]

Tags: ruby, macos, rspec, rubygems

I can't install any ruby gems on this Mac running OSX 10.11.

Here is what happens when I try to install a gem:

> $ gem install rspec
>
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' (>= 0), here is why:
>
> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - connect(2) for "rubygems.org" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

I thought it might be an ssl issue so I tried running

> $ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect rubygems.org:https
>
> connect: Invalid argument
>
> connect:errno=22

Any ideas on what the problem is? Thank you for your time and help

Comment: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/515 This might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [known] issues with SSL on *rubygems.org*, not on your machine. Explicitly set the source to be HTTP, not HTTPS:

```
gem install rspec --source http://rubygems.org
```

In your `Gemfile` (if any) you probably should set:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

as the very top line.